# Locating elements in Protractor vs directly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In one of the tests, I need to *scroll into view* of an element which can be done via [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method *parameterizing* the script with an element located via Protractor:

```
var elm = element(by.id("myid"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());
```

But, we can also find the element directly via [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('myid').scrollIntoView();");
```

What is the difference between the two approaches?

<sup>The `scrollIntoView()` is chosen for sample purposes only. The logic inside the script can be more complex.</sup>

Comment: It's no diff, just one of the many ways javascript can do stuff. The first one takes the element as an argument. The second one finds the element.

Comment: Well for first you will have the control of finding the elements(multiple ways) using selenium. For the second you have to use s alone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one will tell you explicitly when the element is missing while the second one will raise a JavaScript error saying that null doesn't have the .scrollIntoView method. So to keep the second one maintainable, you need to implicitly handle the case when the element is missing and raise an error with an appropriate message.

The first one is exposed to an unexpected/stale state. The element found by `element(by.id("myid"))` could be removed from the page just before executing `browser.executeScript()`. The second one is not exposed to this issue since the page is not updated while the script is executed.

The second one is less expensive since it executes one Selenium command (ExecuteScript), while the first one executes two (FindElement and ExecuteScript). Sending a Selenium command to the browser is relatively expensive (minimum of 25ms) and might become significant with multiple calls.

Both will produce the exact same result and will end up calling the same API on the browser side.

Comment: That's a great overview of the differences and similarities! Thanks! A quick follow-up question for you..I've mentioned somewhere that I've been doing that [eslint plugin for protractor](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor)..I am thinking about warning if there is an `executeScript()` call and `document.getElement..()` methods are used suggesting to locate elements with Protractor and pass the web element via `arguments` into the script. Do you think it makes sense to have this kind of a rule? And, in general, I would appreciate your feedback about this plugin. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't use eslint, but I think it would be a good idea to tag `executeScript`. My opinion is that it should never appear in the tests or page objects and should only be present in a side module to provide additional/extended functionalities. Not sure about ruling the content since it should only be used for advanced/specific reasons.

Comment: Nice idea, created a feature request https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/39. Any other feedback is very much welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A couple things come to mind.

1. Maintenance going forward. What happens if your `.scrollIntoView()` element locator changes? I think I would prefer finding the element using Selenium instead of JS. Reduced chance to have typos, type checking, and so on with an IDE but the IDE won't look into the string that contains your JS.
2. Selenium accessibility. Since Selenium can't see invisible elements, it could affect your choice either way. Would you want an exception to be thrown if you are trying to scroll to an invisible element? Selenium would let you know where JS wouldn't. Maybe you want to intentionally scroll to an invisible element. Finding invisible elements is a job for JS but not Selenium.

There may be more but this is all I can think of off the top of my head.